# Evaluating the Average value of f(x)

Tags: calculus

Determine the average value of $f(x)$ over the interval from $x=a$ to $x=b$, where $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$, $a=\frac{1}{10}$, and $b=10$

[image]

Can someone please explain the simplifying in this problem step-by-step?

Comment: This is not a complete problem. $f(x)$ must be defined as something, likely $\frac{1}{x}$. Additionally, $a$ and $b$ must have values for this to come out to an answer. I can assume they are $10$ and $\frac{1}{10}$, though.

Comment: Determine the average value of f(x) over the interval from x=a, where f(x)=1/x, a=1/10, and b=10

Comment: Mind adding that to your question? Also, your values for $a$ and $b$ conflict with the solution given.

Comment: $\ln$ is an antiderivative of $1/x$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $$\ln\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) = - \ln{x}$$

In particular, we have that

$$\ln{a} - \ln\left(\frac{1}{a}\right) = 2 \ln{a}$$

Hence, we multiply $10$ by $2$ to get $20$.

Comment: can u use the problems numbers

Comment: @Sam I did. You have a $10$ that becomes a $20$, which is what I said in my answer.

Comment: ....ln(12)-ln(12)^-1 = ln(12/12^-1) ...is this correct?

Comment: $\ln{12} - ln(12^{-1}) = \ln{12} - (-ln{12}) =\ln{12} + \ln{12} = 2 \ln{12} $

Answer (score 2):

Your values for $a$ and $b$ differ from the solution you've given, however, here is an answer anyway. Some steps are missing which should help clarify.

$$\frac{1}{b-a}\int_a^bf(x)dx$$

This turns into:

$$\frac{1}{12-\frac{1}{12}}\int_\frac{1}{12}^{12}\frac{1}{x}dx$$

We know that $\int\frac{1}{x}dx=\ln\left|x\right|$.

$$\left.\frac{12}{143}\ln|x|\right]_\frac{1}{12}^{12}$$

We substitue $12$ and $\frac{1}{12}$:

$$\frac{12}{143}\left(\ln(12)-\ln(12^{-1})\right)=\frac{24}{143}\left(\ln 12\right)$$

Comment: how did you get ln(12)? ( this is what i need help on)

Comment: @Sam Please review the fundamentals of integration; $12$ comes from the integral's limits, substituted into the integrand $\ln|x|$.

Comment: i know that but i am not understanding the ln12 in the answer. how did you use the properties of logarithms to get that?

Comment: @Sam Substitute $12$ for $x$ in $\ln|x|$.

Comment: Emrakul also used $\ln(12^{-1}) = -\ln(12)$.